# Create a Top navigation with Silverlight

Tags: navigation, custom, silverlight

I would like to create a custom top navigation bar with silverlight . I want to do it with least possible time and effort . Could you anyone please suggest a link where i can get the code and implement it asap .The value in the top nav should be configurable and this shld be a reusable component.